# What is the best way to solve the ip conflict between two NICs

Tags: iptables

As in the picture, my device got ip through wifi, meanwhile my local NIC has static ip, sometimes they may conflict (user router dhcp's network segment and my local NIC are in the same network segment). How can I solve this problem at the root, configure iptables?

———————————————————————————————
Thanks for the replies to all of you.
I need to add that the actual scenario is more complicated than that, my computer is a product (running linux OS inside) with a local NIC already configured and the wireless NIC is for the user. The user may have various dhcp ip's and there is a risk of conflict. Is there any architecture to solve this problem completely so that all users can use it smoothly.

[image: Network Architecture]

Comment: May be reconfigure A and B and their network to a different unused subnet?

Comment: When you need IPv4 : Allow A and B to use the IPv4 [Link Local addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) on their shared network and don't assign addresses from the RFC 1918 private use subnets and you're unlikely to get overlap when connecting to properly configured WiFi networks

Answer (score 0):

you can restrict the dhcp server to lease out a subset of the full network, so that it will never try to hand out an ip address that you have configured manually.  look for a ip range setting on the dhcp server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in practice I can't control the user's router dhcp settings

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use least likely conflicting address space, that would be to pick from 172.16/12 IP address space.

Comment: And then from that rather large subnet select the minimal sized subnet necessary to get the A & B to communicate i.e. use only a /31 or /30 and the impact of having overlap is reduced further.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when in a network segment the system's default route matching only goes from the higher priority NIC, and the other NIC does not go at all, which is a really hard problem to solve.

Comment: When "B" gets configured by DHCP and the DHCP server runs on "A" you can switch the IP configuration A uses on that shared interface and the DHCP range it offers when that conflicts with whatever gets assigned on the WiFi interface. - But please only post an answer when it answers the question and instead edit the question

Comment: is a trick, but the fact that the local NIC ip is statically configured there are many programs that rely on this ip, so you can not dhcp assignment，It seems that this problem becomes a network isolation requirement